# PyTorch DataLoader has twice the number of labels compared to input

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, train-test-split

I am training a GCN and evaluating its performance on a test set. For consistency with the training set and validation set, I converted the test set to a dataloader with one batch. However, len(data.y) is the twice that of len(pred). The dimension of the model output is likely fine because in train_loader and val_loader, len(data.y) = len(pred) as expected. The difference is in train_loader and val_loader, a batch size of 100 was used.

```
model.eval()

test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset,
    batch_size=len(test_dataset), shuffle=False)

for data in test_loader:
    pred = model(data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch)
    print(len(data.y))
    print(len(pred))
```

I have tried using also a batch size of 100 in the test_loader, but in each batch len(data.y) is still twice that of len(pred).